# How can I add both static text and dynamic variable in mat tooltip angular?

Tags: angular, angular-material, tooltip

How can I add both static text and dynamic variable in mat tooltip angular?

```
<span class="trim" [matTooltip]="Updated at test.updated by test.updated_at.name" > {{test.created_by.email}}</span>
```

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Like so:

```js
<span class="trim" [matTooltip]="'Updated at test.updated by ' + test.updated_at.name" > {{test.created_by.email}}</span>
```

when you put `matTooltip` in Brackets, it means you can use javascript expressions.

Its called Property Binding - http://angular.io/guide/property-binding

Comment: I have included the comment as part of the answer.

Answer (score 5):

Basicly you can call a function in `matTooltip` as below

```
<span class="trim" [matTooltip]="itemtooltiptext()" > {{test.updated_at.name}}</span>
```

typescript

```
test: any = {
    updated: "updated",
    updated_at: {
      name: "errorau"
    }
  };

  itemtooltiptext() {
    return `Updated at ${this.test.updated} by ${this.test.updated_at.name}`;
  }
```

[demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-mat-tooltip-adsui7?file=app/tooltip-overview-example.ts)

Comment: You dont want to make it that way. There is problem with performance once you use function in your template. [See here](https://medium.com/showpad-engineering/why-you-should-never-use-function-calls-in-angular-template-expressions-e1a50f9c0496#:~:text=In%20this%20article%2C%20we%20learned,calls%20in%20Angular%20template%20expressions.)